# How to make my HTML page responsive?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I've created a HTML page and I'd like to make it responsive.
I've looked at the w3schools but didn't figure out how to make it responsive.
I've just add the line

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but it doesn't make the text responsive. I know I have to add something, but can't figure out what.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Test page</title>
<head>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      h1 { font-size: 50px; }
      body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; background: #eaeaea;text-align: center; padding: 150px;}
      article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
      a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; }
      a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }
    </style>
</head>

<article>
        <h1>This is a test page</h1>
        <div>
            <p>
            Test page that I made for fun. I would like to be able to code. <a href="mailto:#">Send me an email (not working)</a></p>
            <p>&mdash; Alessio</p>
        </div>
</article>
```

EDIT:

At the moment I'm playing with the line

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

- Without this line, the entire text fit on a mobile device, but very small. So the page is zoomed out to fit the screen.
- With the line, the text is a good size, but it doesn't fit the screen.

I need something so that I can keep the text size, but make it fit depending on the screen dimension.

I don't want to use library. I'd like to write the code directly in the page (if possible).

EDIT 2:
following the suggestion of @elhampour and @gavgrif I've investigated more the bootstrap. I'm doing a course at freecodecamp.com and now I'm understanding more about this suggestion.
At the moment the code is

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Coming Soon</title>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <h1 class="text-primary text-center">We&rsquo;ll be online soon!</h1>
 <img class="img-responsive col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" src="https://livetogether.xyz/images/LT-header-alpha-flip.ico" alt="livetogether.xyz">
 <p>If you need to you can always <a href="mailto:#">contact us</a>, we&rsquo;ll get back to you shortly!</p>
 <p>&mdash; LiveTogether Team</p>
</div>
```

Now I'm looking to make the text responsive

Comment: you can use bootstrap framework , it is the best known responsive framework, and also i suggest that you read about responsive first. http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use media queries in your CSS to change the sizings etc in different viewports. The following will set the h1 to a 50px size on screens above 768px and to 30px for screens at or below 768px:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   h1 { font-size: 30px; }
    }

@media (min-width: 769px) {
   h1 { font-size: 50px; }
    }
```

As mentioned by @elhampour - investigate Bootstrap and then you can change the layout as well as the sizes etc:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  <p>test content 1</p>
</div>
```

This will display as the full viewport of a mobile (col-xs-), half the width of a small viewport (tablet), a third of a medium viewport (laptop) and a quarter of the larger viewport (descktop screen).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to add? Comment on my question if the following does not answer your question. 

First of all, html pages are already responsive. Your divs will change their size as the page's size changes. Text size cannot be made to fit the screen by default, however you CAN use a library like this: https://plugins.jquery.com/textfill/
If you want to, you could have an event in your javascript which will fire when the document's size is changed, or when it is loaded, and it will customize your page for you, based on your input. This would be done by selecting elements individually and setting their .styles.
Also, css code can be changed as the page is changed. Look into http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp
Good luck with your project, and have a good day!

Comment: Thank you @Evan_K2014, I was thinking to don't use any library. I've already tried to use the w3.css but I prefer to have all the code in that file adding the style I need to make the page looks clear on a mobile too.

Comment: Dude... if you just want a page on mobile, try using bootstrap (go to w3.schools.com and use their tutorials), or make it yourself. There is no magical way to create a mobile page from a desktop page. Each mobile page uses either mobile css code, or literally uses different code.

Comment: that's what I'd like to do, write my own code for that page, but I don't know if it will be super difficult. I thought that maybe it just need a some lines of code. I've already read the doc on w3schools.com and tried different solutions (also using their library w3.css) but I'd like to style the page by myself, only I don't know where to start when it comes to responsive.

Comment: Have you read my answer? Go back and look at the w3schools link. It is NOT w3.css. Here is some code on that page that I particularly want you to see: https://jsfiddle.net/58aeegf4/ This code is code that will change the style of the page, if the width is greater than 480 px. I recommend you use around 800 px for mobile. In other words, if the page is less than 800 px wide, apply your mobile styling. Please understand that as a coder, you will need to do some of the hard work yourself, and not rely on programs to figure out solutions for you.

Comment: I understood the code `@media` and I'm able to change the style of the page triggered by the size of the screen. What I have not clear is what should I put after the `@media screen and (min-width: 800px)` to make the entire text showing on the screen. do I have to rewrite the CSS that I'm using for the laptop mode with different values?